# MySQL Full Text Matching in Boolean Mode Not Matching as I Expect

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, resultset

I have absolutely no experience with MySQL Full Text matching, so there's a good chance the issue I am having is due to my ignorance. I have a data set in a MyISAM table that holds a hierarchy of Regions, and I want to be able to search these regions based upon very simple search terms. For example, the query

```
select *, Match(Name) Against('New*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as rank from RegionSearch where Match(Name) Against('New*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

returns

[image: Screenshot of output 1]

Searching the Database for anything where the name is like 'New%' returns

[image: Screenshot of output 2]

How can I be sure to I am matching everything I need to match using Full Text Searching?

Answer (score 0):

Just make double check your Engine Type

Other wise run bellow Query.

ALTER TABLE `RegionSearch` ENGINE=MYISAM

Comment: I Created this table explicitly as a MyISAM table. This table actually mirrors the contents of another table which uses INNODB, and is to be updated once an hour and used only for searching.